# Assigning struct variable with cli package

Tags: go

I'm writing my first golang app, so go easy on me!

I have a very simple struct:

```
type Output struct {
  Name     string   `json:"name"`
}
```

and I'm also using this golang package to [build a CLI app](https://github.com/urfave/cli):

I want to assign the value of a cli `StringFlag` to the value of the initialized struct. So a boolean flag, I do this:

```
var testing bool
app.Flags = []cli.Flag{
    cli.BoolFlag{Name: "test, T", Usage: "Output to stdout or not", Destination: &testing},
}
```

This works fine.

However, when I try to initialize the struct, and then assign the value in a similar way, it doesn't work:

```
struct_values := &Output { }
app.Flags = []cli.Flag{
    cli.StringFlag{Name: "name, N", Usage: "The name of the thing", Destination: &struct_values.Name},
}
```

What am I missing here? I feel like this is relatively straightforward, but my understanding is lacking :(

Comment: You need to say `var struct_values *Output` instead of reference to a struct, and then you can pass a reference in your cli.StringFlag function

Answer (score 0):

I was making this way harder than it needed to be :)

I went with:

```
struct_values := &Output { Name: c.string("name") }
```

Which got the job done just as easily